# Error in Array to string conversion

Tags: php

I have a query that's retraive a list of id's. Those id's are in an array and i need to save it in table with those id's. I tried using implode to make those id's a string i could use in a where clause but i keep getting this error.

```
$save_food = $_POST['save_food'];
$unserializedData = array();
parse_str($save_food,$unserializedData);
foreach($unserializedData as $unserializedData1){
$query = mysql_query("insert into subscribefood (s_user_id,s_food) values ('$ft_user_id','".implode($unserializedData1, ',')."')");
}
```

Comment: What error's that, then?

Comment: You are doing something really weird

Comment: this the error :- `Array to string conversion`

Comment: @kamgfx Print your $unserializedData & Show me

Comment: `implode()` will give you an array but you need a string. are your sure that you know what you are doing?

Comment: @Nathan Srivi `Array
(
    [foodtype] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 5
        )

)`

Comment: @kamgfx What you want in foreach please explain

Comment: @hek2mgl i need to save this value of array (1,3,5) from `Array ( [foodtype] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 ) )` to my database

Comment: @Nathan Srivi i need to save this value (1,3,5) to my table

Comment: just throw that `implode()` away then it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$save_food = $_POST['save_food'];
$unserializedData = array();
parse_str($save_food,$unserializedData);
$datalist = $unserializedData['foodtype'];
foreach($datalist as $data){
$query = mysql_query("insert into subscribefood (s_user_id,s_food) values ('$ft_user_id','$data')");
}
?>
```

Comment: @hek2mgl he needs to insert all 3 values in separate row so only i am using this.

Comment: @hek2mgl  if you found any wrong please tell me. so only i am update my knowledge.

Comment: @NathanSrivi Now, without the `implode()` it makes sense